# Upcasting related - class conversion

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class, for example:

```
 class BaseDataPoint
 {
     public double A;
     public double B;
 }
```

and later on in the code, I need to extend that to

```
 class ReportDataPoint : BaseDataPoint
 {
     public double C;
 }
```

Since above is only an example, and there are lot more fields to copy, is it possible (via some trick) to 'convert' `BaseDataPoint` instance to `ReportDataPoint` without manually copying field by field?

If I have

```
 BaseDataPoint p1;
 ...
 ReportDataPoint p2=(ReportDataPoint)p1;  // FAILS at runtime
 ReportDataPoint p3=new ReportDataPoint(p1);  //  can't compile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the type of an instance; you need to create a new instance. Furthermore, you can't use the cast syntax for this since you re not allowed to add custom operators within the inheritance chain.

So; either add a manual conversion (via adding a constructor like your example, or a ComvertTo method) - or there are a few libraries that may help (maybe AutoMapper, up it some serialization lins might help too).

Answer (score 1):

Just write a constructor inside ReportDataPoint, so that p3's initialisation will compile. It's work, but it'll enable you to define default values for the newer fields.    class

```
BaseDataPoint
    {
        public double A;
        public double B;
        public BaseDataPoint(double A, double B)
        {
            this.A = A;
            this.B = B;
        }
    }

    class ReportDataPoint : BaseDataPoint
     {
        static const double defaultCValue = 0.0;
        public double C;
        public ReportDataPoint(double A, double B, double C)
         :base(A,B){
            this.C = C;
          }

       public ReportDataPoint(BaseDataPoint p,double C=defaultCValue) :
        this(p.A, p.B, C)
       { }
    }

    ...
    BaseDataPoint p1=new BaseDataPoint(1,2);

    ReportDataPoint p2=new ReportDataPoint(p1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. In cases like this I would just implement a constructor for ReportDataPoint that accepts a BaseDataPoint instance and copies the relevant data.

Answer (score 0):

It only depends on the type of the instance you create.

If you try :

```
BaseDataPoint p1 = new ReportDataPoint();
```

You will be able to cast it later.

otherwise you can implement a generic util class to transfer field values between instance types. once for all.